TypeScript: One type for multiple objects with different properties
It could be solved like this:
type ObjectType = {
    [key: string]: string;
}

but the problem is that typescript is not actually aware of objects' properties and doesn't throw errors if I try to read a property that doesn't exist. Here's an example:
const someObj: ObjectType = {
    key0: 'value0',
    key1: 'value0',
    ...,
    keyN: 'valueN'
};

There are no suggestions after writing someObj. and no ts errors if there's an attempt of accessing a property that doesn't exist, for example, if a property is misspelled like someObj.keu0
Is there a better solution?

You can use the satisfies operator as shown in this playground link; does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (or find a suitable duplication source). If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz thanks, that works perfectly! I also found another solution which involves creating a function const createObject = <T extends ObjectType>(obj: T): T => obj, but your solution seems simpler and more readable

Actually, it's const createObject = <T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T): T => obj

Yeah, that's the way you had to do it before satisfies existed. Please see the linked q/a above for more info.
